# Convert- Inline ng-repeat filter to custom filter - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-online">
    Filter by Online 
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-online" ng-model="vm.online" class="form-control" ng-options="online for online in vm.onlines">
        <option value="">All</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form class="col2">
    <label for="filter-productType">
    Filter by Product Type
  </label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="filter-productType" ng-model="vm.productType" class="form-control" ng-options="productType for productType in vm.productTypes">
      <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <table style="margin-top: 30px">
    <tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | filter:{online:vm.online || undefined, productType: vm.productType || undefined}">
      <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
      <td>{{lim.productType}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.onlines = ["Men", "Kids", "Ladies"];
    vm.productTypes = ["Shirt", "Shoe", "Belt", "Top"];
    vm.stockLimits = [{
      id: 1,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shirt"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      online: "Men",
      productType: "Shoe"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: "Belt"
    }, {
      id: 4,
      online: "Ladies",
      productType: "Top"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      online: "Kids",
      productType: null
    }]
  })
```

I want to declare the custom filter to filter online and productType and call the custom filter from angular html template. Above inline filter works fine but i look forward to convert the inline filter to custom filter. Actually want to move the filter function from html page.
Note: productType can be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom filter following way

```
angular.module("myApp").filter('productFilter', function() {
    return function(items, filterOptions) {
        if (!items) {
            return []
        }

        return items.filter(function(item) {
            var isOnlinePassed = filterOptions.online ? (item.online === filterOptions.online) : true,
                isProductTypePassed = filterOptions.productType ? (item.productType === filterOptions.productType) : true;
            return isOnlinePassed && isProductTypePassed;

        })
    }
})
```

And then use the filter in your template like:

```
  <table style="margin-top: 30px">
    <tr ng-repeat="lim in vm.stockLimits | productFilter:{online:vm.online , productType: vm.productType}">
      <td>{{lim.online}}</td>
      <td>{{lim.productType}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you but there is one issue which i m not able to figure it out when i integrate this filter in my existing angular js module. If i have second parameter is not empty in angular.module("myApp", 'service'), filtering is not working

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productFilterFilterProvider <- productFilterFilter

Comment: Browser issue i guess. Now it works as expected. Great work. Thanks. :)